# Having difficulty with pandas melt

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some difficulty using pandas melt. I tried to follow the iris example with my data set but I end up with a data frame which I cannot explain. It also isn't what I was hoping to get.

My dataset looks like this:

```
        Type         Airline  Count
0    neutral  Virgin America    171
1   positive  Virgin America    152
2   negative  Virgin America    181
3   positive          United    492
4   negative          United   2633
5    neutral          United    697
6   negative       Southwest   1186
7    neutral       Southwest    664
8   positive       Southwest    570
9   positive           Delta    544
10   neutral           Delta    723
11  negative           Delta    955
12  negative      US Airways   2263
13   neutral      US Airways    381
14  positive      US Airways    269
15  negative        American   1960
16   neutral        American    463
17  positive        American    336
```

But the result I receive is:

```
   Type  Airline           value
0    neutral  Airline  Virgin America
1   positive  Airline  Virgin America
2   negative  Airline  Virgin America
3   positive  Airline          United
4   negative  Airline          United
5    neutral  Airline          United
6   negative  Airline       Southwest
7    neutral  Airline       Southwest
8   positive  Airline       Southwest
9   positive  Airline           Delta
10   neutral  Airline           Delta
11  negative  Airline           Delta
12  negative  Airline      US Airways
13   neutral  Airline      US Airways
14  positive  Airline      US Airways
15  negative  Airline        American
16   neutral  Airline        American
17  positive  Airline        American
18   neutral    Count             171
19  positive    Count             152
20  negative    Count             181
21  positive    Count             492
22  negative    Count            2633
23   neutral    Count             697
24  negative    Count            1186
25   neutral    Count             664
26  positive    Count             570
27  positive    Count             544
28   neutral    Count             723
29  negative    Count             955
30  negative    Count            2263
31   neutral    Count             381
32  positive    Count             269
33  negative    Count            1960
34   neutral    Count             463
35  positive    Count             336
```

And so when I try to use the swarmplot I get the error.

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Count'
```

Below is the code I am using,

```
airline_data = pd.melt(airline_data, "Type", var_name="Airline")
print(airline_data)

# Draw a categorical scatterplot to show each observation
sns.swarmplot(x="Airline", y="Count", hue="Type",
              palette=["r", "c", "y"], data=airline_data)
```

My desired outcome is to create a swarmplot like the one from the iris data set.

Comment: In my opinion `melt` here is not necessary, try remove `airline_data = pd.melt(airline_data, "Type", var_name="Airline")` only.

Comment: Thank you @jezael! That worked. I obviously don't have a good understanding of how "melt" works! Thank you